# Resize columns of HTML table working after page refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have developed some HTML pages which contain a table with several columns, but I am facing a problem: the columns cannot be resized untill the page is refreshed.

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue and helping me understand the reason why is this happening?

Comment: Please add some code to narrow the problem, so that we can give you an appropriate answer. Without that, you can only expect comments asking *"what"* , *"where"* and *"why"*.

Comment: Add a fiddle of your code: www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Added refresh on load of page and problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added refresh on load of page and problem got resolved.